# MySQL add values from one column but various rows into one column per row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a column to an SQL table.
The table contains object posted persons. The object are not unique but the timestamp is.
I want to add a column for every object containing the names of persons who also posted that object per row.

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| ID    | name  | timeXX |
+-------+-------+--------+
| ID001 | name1 | timeXX |
| ID001 | name2 | timeXY |
| ID001 | name1 | timeYX |
| ID002 | name2 | timeZX |
| ID002 | name1 | timeYZ |
| ID002 | name3 | timeXZ |
| ID002 | name1 | timeZZ |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

I would like to end up with something like

```
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
| ID    | name  | time   | grouped_name  |
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
| ID001 | name1 | timeXX | name2         |
| ID001 | name2 | timeXY | name1         |
| ID001 | name1 | timeYX | name2         |
| ID002 | name2 | timeZX | name1, name3  |
| ID002 | name1 | timeYZ | name2, name3  |
| ID002 | name3 | timeXZ | name1, name2  |
| ID002 | name1 | timeZZ | name2, name3  |
+-------+-------+--------+---------------+
```

Would this be possible. And if so, how? I would love to know!

Thanks for your help, regards,

Ruud

Comment: Do you mean you want the table to physically include a new column that would contain that data?  Or do you mean you want a query that returns the data in the table, plus this new value?

Comment: I would prefer the first. Second option would also work when stored as view. Right?

Comment: You shouldn't change the table that way without a very good reason. That would denormalize your schema.

Comment: So how would you suggest to do this? Creating a view for this purpose wouldn't bother me either.

Comment: Use JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT. I can't help without the definitions of all involved tables.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select t.id,t.name,t.time,(
select group_concat(DISTINCT t2.name separator ',')
from times t2 where t2.id=t.id  AND (t.time like concat('%',substring(REPLACE (t2.time,'time', ''),1,1),'%')
OR t.time like concat('%',substring(REPLACE (t2.time,'time', ''),2,1),'%')) AND t2.name<>t.name
group by t2.id 
) as time_group from times t
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the respons and feedback. It has helped me a lot.

For now I found an answer in the following solutions. Not totally the result I want, but I can work withit.

```
SELECT * ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `name`) AS `grouped_name` FROM table GROUP BY `time`
```

For the best result I would like to substract the name of the row the `grouped_name` is added to from the `grouped_name`.

But for now this works well enough. I guess my initial question wasn't clear enough due to translating my question into english and doing stuff I'm not fully in to (mySQL).

Many thanks!

Regards,

Ruud